# Symfony & Doctrine InnerJoin

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony

I'm trying do a join with doctrine query builder.

```
$query = $this->createQueryBuilder('od');
$query->innerJoin(Order::class, 'o', Expr\Join::WITH, 'o.orderid = od.orderid');
$query->where('o.userid = :userid')
$query->andWhere('od.orderstatusid IN (:orderstatusid)')
$query->setParameter('userid', $userid);
$query->setParameter('orderstatusid', array(5, 6, 7, 8, 10))
```

The request failed because the generate SQL is :

```
SELECT od FROM OrderDetail od INNER JOIN Order o WITH o.orderid = od.orderid WHERE o.userid = :userid AND od.orderstatusid IN (:orderstatusid)
```

Or it should be

```
SELECT od FROM OrderDetail od INNER JOIN Order o ON o.orderid = od.orderid WHERE o.userid = :userid AND od.orderstatusid IN (:orderstatusid)
```

I cant use $query->innerJoin(Order::class, 'o', Expr\Join::ON, 'o.orderid = od.orderid'); because i got this error :

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 91: Error: Expected Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Lexer::T_WITH, got 'ON'
```

If i dont use join condition, doctrine doesnt get it from the model so i dont have the good results.

How can you have a join and a where with querybuilder ?

Thanks for your help

Edit :
This is the model :

```
OrderDetail:
    type: entity
    table: order_detail
    repositoryClass: OrderDetailRepository
    id:
        orderdetailid:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
    fields:
        ...
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
    manyToOne:
        order:
            targetEntity: Order
            inversedBy: orderdetails
            joinColumn:
                name: orderid
                referencedColumnName: orderid


Order:
    type: entity
    table: order
    id:
        orderid:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
    fields:

    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
    oneToMany:
        orderdetails:
            targetEntity: OrderDetail
            mappedBy: order
            fetch: EAGER
```

Comment: What you're doing looks OK. WITH is DQL, not SQL, are you sure that is the actual generated SQL? Also, please post your entity relationships as well.

Comment: I edit with my model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking out your entities I think your query can be simplified a bit. You don't actually need the WITH at all.

```
    $result = $this->createQueryBuilder('od')
        ->join('od.order', 'o')
        ->addSelect('o')
        ->where('o.userid = :userid')
        ->andWhere('od.orderstatusid IN (:orderstatusid)')
        ->setParameter('userid', $userid)
        ->setParameter('orderstatusid', array(5, 6, 7, 8, 10))
        ->getQuery()->getResult()
    ;
```

Doctrine is smart enough to know that od.order means the OrderDetail -> Order relationship and manage that join for you. You only really need to use WITH when you have some pretty specific query requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In [Doctrine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html) documentation explain this:

```
$qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', Expr\Join::WITH, $qb->expr()->eq('u.status_id', '?1'));
```

OR

```
$qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', 'WITH', 'u.status = ?1');
```

OR

```
$qb->innerJoin('u.Group', 'g', 'WITH', 'u.status = ?1', 'g.id');
```

I recommend use this way:

```
$query->innerJoin('od.Order', 'o', 'WITH', 'od.orderstatusid IN (:orderstatusid)');
```

This way query is most optimtimal and don't need use "o.orderid = od.orderid" and "$query->andWhere('od.orderstatusid IN (:orderstatusid)')".

Comment: If i use it, the join is not good, i have to specifie the join keys orderid